# How to do a pow function inside of while? C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

Here is the problem I must do(Just for context): Write a program that will input 2 integers from the user, will then calculate the first to the power of the second and then output the result. The Input, calculation and output should be in three separate subprograms/functions. You must calculate the exponentiation using a WHILE loop and multiplying the first number, the required number of times. For this homework only, you are allowed to use global variables to move information between functions. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double a, b, ans;


int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter two whole numbers: ";
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << conclusion() << calc();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int calc()
{
    double ans = pow(a, b);
    return 0;
}

int conclusion()
{
    cout << a << " To the power of " << b
         << " is " << ans;
    return 0;
}
```

So here's what I'm having an issue with, I do online classes. The dude is like, "here's a problem, figure it out and just do it." Which is fine I guess, but when things like this come up its hard to find certain tutorials and questions. Anyway, I got my BASE code down. Now I need a while loop, and have no idea what this means: calculate the exponentiation using a WHILE loop and multiplying the first number, the required number of times.
I figured I could just do a while and do

```
double ans = pow(a, b);
```

But that's not the case apparently. That's what my chapter taught me, but not with a while and all this extra stuff you need to do for this. I asked a classmate, she said she had a really difficult time as well, and her example to me was:

```
int a = 0;

int b =  0;

int c = 1;

cin >> a;

cin >> b;

int powerOp(int a, int b, int c)
{

while (b > 0)
          {
               c = c * a;

               b--;
          }
               cout  <<  c;
               return c;
}
```

I have been working almost all day and can't figure this out. I don't understand why we need to factorize and set the int = 1. I thought it could simply be

```
double ans = pow(a, b); //a and b being the 2 numbers the user inputs
```

Comment: Since you are doing it using a loop and I guess its the requirement of your assignment (not to use pow())

Comment: I think you're being asked to use a `while` loop _instead_ of using `pow` (i.e. instead of `pow(a,b);`, use `while (--b) c *= a;`)

Comment: It's not about the answer, it's about understanding how to implement the algorithm.

Comment: Which is exactly why I'm asking if anyone could explain how or why... or give me something solid to study off of. Not the answer. I hate people that like to assume everyone's cheats and don't read the entire thing.

Comment: Why are you using global variables? That aside change `double ans = pow(a, b);` to `ans = pow(a, b);`

Comment: I put it in the explanation that my teacher said we could use global variables, I haven't really mastered the art of local variables, and figured they would make things more confusing while I did this. I'm in my 6th week of college and am trying my best

Comment: Take the time and get a grip on local variables. It's a good investment. Save you a lot of effort in the long run.

Comment: Avoid global variables like the plague. They are bad news and should only be used if no other option is available

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I've found the solution. I will definitely look into doing local variables and improving this code after turning this in.

Comment: "For this homework only, you are allowed to use global variables to move information between functions"... No. Comment.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple, lets say you have 2^3. You and I both agree that it is the same as doing 2x2x2. You mutiplied you first number A by itself B (your second number) times. Now for your loop, what you want have your second number server as your counter AND loop exit condition. Something like this

```
double YourPowerFunction(int a, int b)
{
    int counter = 0;
    double result = 1;

    while (counter < b)
    {
        counter++:
        result = result * a;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the example and your explanation. I was trying to fiddle around with the code and understand it a bit more. I might be commenting back to soon. I guess what I was trying to say in my original post, is that I understand the code, but I don't get WHY or the math behind it. All I know is what to do by the examples my classmates have been giving me. I feel like I'm not actually learning it unless if I know why. I get the 2^3 example. Not sure what counter is or why it needs to be there.. I'm sorry if I'm a bit lost.

Comment: @DallasRose walk through the instructions of the code by keeping track of the variables on a piece of paper and watch what happens and how counter  stops the loop from looping.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this example and it wasn't working at all for me.(Yes, I fiddled around with it all night!) The only way I got it to work was with my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I'm pretty sure I found the answer. Result is the variable for ans

```
int calc() //function for calculation
{

    //Still not sure how I did this one, after hours of playing around with it
    while (b > 0) //This code is adding a 0 in the result. I can't figure it out
    {
        result = result * a;
        b--;
    }

    return (result);
}
```

This is just a simple solution, as it wants to add a 0 in the end result.